# Shell script for connecting to DB2 database is not working

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, db2

I have written a shell script for connecting to a DB2 database. This script lists out the databases on DB2 server and connects to the database after user enters the desired database name. But after the script runs with a successful db connection info, when I try to run a command against the database it says that the database connection does not exist. SQLSTATE=08003

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#DBA DB2 Script: DB connection script-connectdb
#Created By : Ashish Verma
#Creation Date : 04/27/2019
#
#Purpose: This script connects to and activates the database

#printf "Below is the list of databases"
DBLIST=`db2 list db directory | grep -i alias | awk '{print $4}'`#This stores all the available databases in DBLIST
USER=`whoami`
echo "Following are the list of available database(s)"
echo "----------------------------------------------"
for db in $DBLIST; do
        echo $db#Present the user will all available databases to choose and input
done
printf "\nEnter the name of the database you wish to connect to:  "
read CHOICE#User enters tha db name 
DB=`db2 "connect to $CHOICE user $USER"`##connection to database is made and output stored in variable DB
if [ -z "$(echo $DB | awk '{print $18}')" ]; then
        printf "Database connection failed! Please check the below error: "#Prints if database is not connected to
        printf "\n$DB\n"
else
        printf "\nYou are connected to database $DB\n"#Prints successful connection
fi

#End of Script
```

After running the above script a database connection is made successfully and line "You are connected to database $DB" is printed". Any command that is run against the database from the shell should be successful.
Eg: db2 list tablespaces;
But even after a successful database connection is made in the above script, when I try to run a command against the database, it says that the database connection does not exist and I have to gain fire the "db2 connect to database db_name" command from the shell to manipulate the database. Can someone please help me why do I need to fire the connect to database command even after running the above script successfully?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more - especially why you think that the connection should persist? Where the error is occurring in the shell script? FWIW, the line DBLIST=`db2 ...` will execute the db2 command. db2 will do whatever it does (e.g. generate the list) and terminate. Why? Because if it did not terminate, the pipeline that sets DBLIST will never end. As long as the db2 command runs, it will hold open stdout and none of the rest can complete. Now, if db2 terminates, which it must for DBLIST (or DB= etc) then it is unlikely that connection would remain open.

Comment: Please refer to
[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The behaviour you see is "working as designed" because the connection from bash gets automatically closed as soon as your script exits.

Comment: @mao Can you please suggest what can be done in this case? How can I create a script that does not close connection from bash while exiting?

Answer (score 2):

What I recommend is to establish the connection as a command directly in your code and not as part of the assignment of a variable that creates a subshell.

```
db2 connect to $CHOICE user $USER
```

After that, just check the error code and not the generated output.

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
  echo error
  exit 1
fi
```

If you really need to process the output, then redirect the db2 output to a file (even a tempfile) and process the output via reading the file (cat).

Never take the output to a variable via a subshell, like

```
`db2 ...`
```

or `$(db2 ...)`.